# Compile a Polymer app in Dart

Tags: javascript, compilation, dart, polymer

I am using Dart 0.8.10_r30104 (DEV) and find it unable to generate the Javascript (the app itself can run in Dartrium, though).

Errors prompted when I choose to "Generate Javascript" on builder.dart:

```
--- Nov 12, 2013 7:35:43 AM Running dart2js... ---
F:\dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.bat --out=E:\My Books\Sitepoint\Sample\build.dart.js E:\My Books\Sitepoint\Sample\build.dart
/E:/My Books/Sitepoint/Sample/packages/polymer/builder.dart:83:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
   ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/My Books/Sitepoint/Sample/packages/polymer/src/build/linter.dart:11:8: Error: Library not found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
   ^^^^^^^^^
/E:/My Books/Sitepoint/Sample/packages/barback/src/asset.dart:9:8: Error: Library not    found 'dart:io'.
import 'dart:io';
   ^^^^^^^^^
...
/E:/My Books/Sitepoint/Sample/packages/analyzer/src/generated/element.dart:7220:17: Hint: The class 'VoidTypeImpl' overrides 'operator==', but not 'get hashCode'.
   bool operator ==(Object object) => identical(object, this);
            ^^
/E:/My Books/Sitepoint/Sample/packages/analyzer/src/generated/element.dart:4874:17:     Hint: The class 'PropertyAccessorElementImpl' overrides 'operator==', but not 'get hashCode'.
  bool operator ==(Object object) => super == object && identical(isGetter, ((object as PropertyAccessorElement)).isGetter);
            ^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

===

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To generate JS for a polymer app, you need to run "pub build" at the top level of your application. This will create a top level directory called build, which will include your JS (and html that points at the JS).

Comment: Note: in order to run pub build, or use the 'Build Polymer App' menu option, you need to set up your pubspec.yaml with a special transformers section (see https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/jdoLc_roMLI/8Es_AH6P8U8J).

Comment: Thanks for both for your inputs. dgrove's point solves the compilation for my "default" polymer app. I tried what Siggi mentioned in the post but not successful yet. Will keep trying.

Comment: Managed to build out the JS version of my app. Thanks for all's attention and useful hints.